# StackOverflowException when trying to generate documentation with SandCastle when project references MassTransit

Tags: .net, documentation, sandcastle

I am trying to build documentation for a project using SandCastle via Sandcastle Help File Builder(http://shfb.codeplex.com/).

It is all working find, *until* I add a reference to the MassTransit (http://masstransit-project.com/) dlls.

Once I do that, I get a `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.`

What could be causing this?

Full SHFB output below:

```
-------------------------------
[Sandcastle Help File Builder Utilities, version 1.9.1.0]
Creating output and working folders...
-------------------------------
Finding tools...
Found Sandcastle tools in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Sandcastle\'
-------------------------------
Validating and copying documentation source information
Source: C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\MessageHandlerFramework.csproj
    Found project 'C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\MessageHandlerFramework.csproj'
Source: C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\sandCastleDoc\MessageHandlerFramework.XML

Parsing project files
    Found assembly 'C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\bin\Debug\MessageHandlerFramework.dll'

References to use:
    MassTransit, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL
    System
    System.configuration
    System.Core
    System.Data
    System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    System.Xml
    System.Xml.Linq

Copying XML comments files
    C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\sandCastleDoc\MessageHandlerFramework.XML -> C:\prj\Merged\documentation\Help\Working\MessageHandlerFramework.XML
SHFB: Warning BE0063: 'C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\bin\Debug\MessageHandlerFramework.XML' matches a previously copied comments filename.  The duplicate will be copied to a unique name to preserve the comments it contains.
    C:\prj\Merged\MessageHandlerFramework\bin\Debug\MessageHandlerFramework.XML -> C:\prj\Merged\documentation\Help\Working\{b528b410-11ff-4d99-8c37-c992a185fb52}
-------------------------------
Generating shared content files (en-US, English (United States))...
    Last step completed in 00:00:00.0070
-------------------------------
Generating API filter for MRefBuilder...
    Last step completed in 00:00:00.0050
-------------------------------
Generating reflection information...
[C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe]
GenerateRefInfo:
  MrefBuilder (v2.6.10621.1)
  Copyright c Microsoft 2006
  Info: Loaded 1 assemblies for reflection and 8 dependency assemblies.

  Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
    Last step completed in 00:00:11.9062
-------------------------------

SHFB: Error BE0064: BUILD CANCELLED BY USER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in the MRefBuilder component that is fixed in Sandcastle 2.7.0.0

"Fixed TypeNode.NestedTypes so that it won't get stuck in an endless loop when a type contains a nested type that itself implements a nested type from within the containing type."